# How to accomplish inheriting Javadoc comments from JDK with Gradle Javadoc task?

Tags: gradle, javadoc, inheritdoc

I want my Javadoc to inherit comments from standard JDK classes. For this, I need to add JDK sources to `-sourcepath` javadoc option. Not to generate documentation for JDK classes themselves, I would specify packages via `-packagenames` or `-subpackages` javadoc options, but Javadoc Gradle task doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this appeared to be pretty easy

```
javadoc {
    configure((CoreJavadocOptions) getOptions()) {
        addStringOption('sourcepath', project.hasProperty('jdkSrc') ? jdkSrc :
            "$System.env.JAVA_HOME/src")
    }
}
```